# vue.js best way to update entire array

Tags: vue.js

What is the best way to update the entire observed array and trigger a rerender in vue.js without having to iterate an push all the items?

I have read the documentation here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array

But it doesn't make sense to me having to filter, concat or slice just to update the array? There must be something I missed?

Comment: What do you mean by *update*? add item, replace item or delete item?

Comment: I mean replace all items with a new array

Comment: So why not just replace it like `oldArr = newArr`?

Comment: `yourArray.splice('deleteCount') //deletes all inputs`
With Babel: `yourArray.push(... yourNewArray) //pushes all new items`

or use `vm.$set(...)` but i do not recommend using `$set`

Comment: As far as I know oldArr = newArr doesn't trigger an vue render update?

Comment: But what happens when you try it? (Assigning the entire array is not one of the [caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats))

Comment: Seems my initial assumption that oldArr = newArr wouldn't trigger a vue update was based on a coding error and a misunderstanding of the documentation. Choasia and Roy are correct it is not one of the caveats. And I got it to work now. Thanks you guys! How do I cancel the question?

Comment: It's a valid question that could be useful for future reference. You can write up your own answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As suggested I will repond to this myself to help anyone in the same predicament.

```
oldArr = newArr
```

should still work (thank you [choasia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6279569/choasia). Even though it is somewhat unclear in the vue.js documentation. Replacing the entire array will not fall under the [caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) mentioned there (thank you [Roy J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j) ).

One option might also be to to empty the array and then push the new one like:

```
yourArray.push(... yourNewArray)
```

Thank you [reiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6355502/reiner)

Comment: it doesn't call component update for children's, in case I pass array as prop

Answer (score 4):

i just use

> this.myArray = this.myArray.slice();

[read about it here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array)

Answer (score 2):

Set the initial arrays length to 0 and then merge them together:

```js
oldArr.length = 0
oldArr.concat(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well, and a lot of sample code out there from Vue 1.0 gives incorrect information on this topic.  So I thought it might be helpful to post my findings in followup to Janspeed's correct answer on this topic.

For example, given an array defined in the `data:` block as follows:

```
  data: {
    event: { name: '', description: '', date: '' },
    events: []
  }
```

To set the entire array (in these examples, to the a local array `var localEvents`), these both work just fine, and you have a bit more flexibility with the second method:

```
this.events = localEvents; // assigns array, is reactive
this.events = localEvents.slice(0, localEvents.length); // assigns array, is reactive
```

You will see samples like this in tutorials, it doesn't work:

```
this.set$("events", localEvents)
```

It will result in this error:

```
Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: events
```

Per: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-set-removed

However, `Vue.set` can be used to *reactively add elements* to an array. Therefore, given an array with length 3:

```
Vue.set(this.events, 4, newEvent); // adds newEvent to array reactively
this.events.splice(4, 1, newEvent); // also adds newEvent to array reactively
```

Of course, per the examples in the documentation, if you specify an index value corresponding to a existing array element, it will be replaced by your input object (`newEvent` in the examples above).

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace an entire array and create a new reactive array, the easiest way is to use one of the supported array manipulation methods which are eg. `.concat()`:

```js
this.newArray = this.oldArray.concat()
```

Using `this.newArray = this.oldArray` will clone reactivity from one array to another, so changes to `this.oldArray` will also be reflected on `this.newArray` which is usually not a behaviour you want to achieve.

You can also check other supported array manipulation methods in Vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods