# Vue.js component array misrenders when replaced with shorter array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I'm introducing myself to **Vue.js (version 2.5.16)** but am running into a problem understanding what looks like a problem with **Reactivity**:

I have two lists of components with `v-for` loops that render correctly most of the time - I can interact with the components and add new components. The components interact with a REST API representing 'zones', and whose function I'm hoping is rather obvious - It mostly returns JSON representations of either a single or all 'zones' for example:

```
{
    "state": "off",
    "pin": 24,
    "uri": "/zones/6",
    "name": "extra"
}
```

Whenever a zone is added or removed, the app *reloads the entire list of zones*. However, for some reason, **when I delete a zone and trigger a reload of the zones, the list gets rendered with the wrong data**! No matter which zone I delete, the last item of the list appears to be 'popped', rather than the expected zone not showing up on the new list! When I inspect the app.zones data, *everything appears correct in the Javascript data* but it just doesn't show up right in the browser.

Here's the relevant code:

```
...
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="control" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <ul>
            <zone-control
                v-for="zone in zones"
                v-bind:init-zone="zone"
                v-bind:key="zone.id">
            </zone-control>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="setup" class="tab-pane fade">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Pin</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr is="zone-setup"
                    v-for="zone in zones"
                    v-bind:init-zone="zone"
                    v-bind:key="zone.id">
                </tr>
                <tr is="zone-add"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
...
<script>
    Vue.component('zone-control', {
        props: ['initZone'],
        template:
            `<li>
                <div class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="toggleState">
                    <span v-if="zone.state == 'on'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle text-success"></span>
                    <span v-else class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign text-danger"></span>
                    Zone: {{ zone.name }}
                </div>
            </li>`,
        data: function() {
            return {
                zone: this.initZone
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toggleState: function() {
                var state = (this.zone.state == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
                console.log('Turning zone ' + this.zone.name + ' ' + state);
                var comp = this
                fetch(
                    this.zone.uri,
                    {method: 'PUT',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }),
                    body: JSON.stringify({state: state})
                }).then( function(result) {
                    return result.json()
                }).then( function(data) {
                    comp.zone = data;
                });
            }
        }
    })

    Vue.component('zone-setup', {
        props: ['initZone'],
        template:
            `<tr>
                <td>{{ zone.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ zone.pin }}</td>
                <td><div v-on:click="deleteZone" class="btn btn-danger btn-small"></div></td>
            </tr>`,
        data: function() {
            return {
                zone: this.initZone
            };
        },
        methods: {
            deleteZone: function() {
                fetch(
                    this.zone.uri,
                    {method: 'DELETE'}
                ).then( function(result) {
                    app.load_zones();
                });
            }
        }
    })

    Vue.component('zone-add', {
        template:
            `<tr>
                <td><input v-model="zone.name" type="text" class="form-control"></input></td>
                <td><input v-model="zone.pin" type="text" class="form-control"></input></td>
                <td><div v-on:click="addZone" class="btn btn-success btn-small"></div></td>
            </tr>`,
        data: function() {
            return {
                zone: {
                    name: '',
                    pin: ''
                }
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addZone: function() {
                console.log('Adding zone ' + this.zone.name);
                var comp = this
                fetch(
                    "/zones",
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: new Headers({
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }),
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            name: comp.zone.name,
                            pin: comp.zone.pin})
                    }
                ).then( function(result) {
                    app.load_zones()
                    comp.zone = {}
                });
            }
        }
    })
    
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            zones: []
        },
        methods: {
            load_zones: function() {
                fetch("zones")
                .then(function(result){
                    return result.json()
                }).then(function(data){
                    app.zones = data;
                });
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.load_zones();
        }
    })
</script>
```

I've read through several references and there seem to be some edge cases or other 'gatchas' but this doesn't seem to fall into any of those. For example, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730610/vue-js-best-way-to-update-entire-array) seems to agree that replacing the whole array is a pretty fool-proof way of altering arrays within the constraints of the Vue.js reactivity system.

Some other links to **Vue.js documentation** that I've checked and that are relevant but don't seem to point to my problem:

[Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

[List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

[Common Beginner Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

**For the full code in context**, see the github repo [here](https://github.com/jusdino/PiSprinkle).

### UPDATE

Per the comments, I've reproduced the symptoms in a simplified [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wepevop/edit?html,js,output). Click on any the button to see that, when the second element should be removed, the last one gets removed instead!

Comment: Have you tried: `Vue.set(app, zones, data);` rather than `app.zones = data` ?

Comment: Did now. I changed the line to `Vue.set(app, 'zones', data);`. No change in behavior.

Comment: you'll need to duplicate the problem in Plunker or JSBin or something. Then we can take a look.

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out: It's all about the `v-bind:key`. I realized that I'm binding to an attribute that isn't provided by the API I'm fetching data from. Reference that to a (real and) unique attribute for each component and the problem goes away.

I did notice that the [List Rendering Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component) mentions that

> In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required.

Interestingly, the `JSBin` I linked above notably uses **Vue.js version 2.0.3** but the problem still exists there and is fixed by proper use of the `key` attribute in the `v-for` loop.

If anyone else wants to see that, look at the `JSBin` linked in the question and add a `v-bind:key="zone.id"` to the `<tr>` element. The problem is resolved after that.